# How to read trainingfaces_24-24.vec with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, dataset

In OpenCV data source is a file named trainingfaces_24-24.vec - which is some dataset of face images. How can I read it in OpenCV and display?

Answer (score 0):

There is a class in imagestorage.h\imagestorage.cpp, its name is "PosReader ". It implements the reading of .vec files. Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can read the contents of a vector file by using "`opencv_createsamples -vec vectorFileName -w width -h height` "
replace with your vector file name width and height given at the time of generating samples . hope this helps.